# Domain driven design - incremental save from UI

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am new to DDD, reading literature on it, but having trouble applying some concepts. 
I am presenting a simplified view of app that I am building. It is a home loan application system. UI has wizard like steps to collect information, like step 1 is collect applicant info, step 2 is collect property info, step 3 is to capture decision of approval or decline. Each application gets assigned a unique ID at step 1. My challenge is how to model incremental save from each step.
Loan application is my aggregate root. From what I read, each root has only one repository and entire root has to be saved together so that it is valid. However UI collects info incrementally and at each step, application entity is valid - when I save data from step 1, my loan application object  is valid. When data from step 2 is saved, loan application object is still valid. 
Looking for some advice on How to design Api and repository here? If agg root is valid at each step and can be saved in small steps, then what’s the point of one save api exposed? Should there be 3 separate Api exposed to UI and these 3 api call 3 separate repo classes or 1 api calling 3 separate methods on one repo? I am using entity framework for save to db. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements of the application and the way you model this will impact how you do it.

*(Note: I will use AR for aggregate root)*

In your case if you have **LoanApplication AR** it needs to contain information about the **Applicant** and the **Property**.

Lets say that each **Applicant** will have something like an unique *account*, so you can keep track of how many loans an **Applicant** has.

In this scenario the **Applicant** will be an entity and probably an **AR**. It will have it's own repository: **ApplicantRepository**. In this case **Applicant AR** needs to be referenced from your **LoanApplication AR**.

This means that in the first step of your wizard you can either search for an **Applicant** using **ApplicantRepository** or create a new one. In case of creating a new one you can create and save it in the first step. Later you can reference the **Applicant** (by reference or by ID) from **LoanApplication**

If you don't want that, then **Applicant** can be a **value object** and it's information will be stored in the **LoadApplication AR**.

The same thing applies to **Property**: you can either have a **Property** Entity with a **PropertyRepository** or just store **PropertyInfo** **value object** to **LoadApplication AR**.

Another important thing is that you **LoanApplication** has a *life-cycle*. Depending on it's current state, the invariant for it may change. It's OK to have an **AR** that will go through different phases. Take for example online stores. When you order something say from Amazon, your order can be Approved or Pending (or in other states) and this is part of it's *life-cycle*. When you want to complete the order the system it may ask you for payment details before submitting it.

In your ca you can create a *life-cycle* for **LoadApplication** by having a Status: *Pending*, *SubmittedForApproval*, *Approved*, *Rejected* etc. It may also need additional information about why it was *Rejected* etc.

If you want to save information about the process of creating a **LoadApplication** you can assign a Status that represents the fact that you **LoadApplication** is still in process of creation: *Pending* or *InProgress*. This way if your application crashes in the middle it can resume by getting the **LoadApplication** and checking it's Status.

You can add behavior in **LoadApplication AR** related to it's status (for example it wont allow a transition to *Approved* status if it's not in *SubmittedForApproval* status and wont allow to change the **Property** if it's not in *InProgress* status (you don't want to change the **Property** or **Applicant** when the status is Approved or SubmittedForApproval).

Implementing Save:

If you have decided that the **LoadApplication Aggregate** will contains three entities: **LoadApplication**, **Applicant** and **Property**, then all these entities are saved and loaded together because the aggregate is a **Transactional Boundary**. This guideline can help in implementing Save, but it can be tricky.

It will depend on several factors:

- What is you database (SQL, MongoDB)?
- Are you using a framework (NHibernate, Mongoose) or using native API (using raw SQL)?

Since only the **LoadApplicationRepository** will Save the **LoadApplication** with **Applicant** and **Property** then there is no problem even if the **Applicant** is saved again to the DB as there will be no changes to it. You will only override existing data with the same data, not so cool for performance, but it's not an issue with your logic.

On the other hand if you are using an ORM they can detect changes in Objects and generate only the required query to update only the new changes to the database. In this case if you say add a **Property** to **LoadApplication** if will pick that up and update only the **Property** in the database.

For example lets say you are using SQL database with (N)Hibernate or EntityFramewok, your ORM will track changes that a Property was added and generate SQL to insert it to **Properties** table in the DB but won't generate insert of update for the already existing **Applicant** because it didn't change.

If you are writing your own logic using for example raw SQL, then you will have to write the logic that tracks changes yourself.

One way is to add changes collection in **LoanApplicaton AR** that will contain changes/events (ApplicantAssigned, PropertyAssigned, SomethingChanged etc) so you can use them in Save method to generate SQL based on changes. When you Save the Aggregate you can Clear the changes.

Here is a great essay on modeling aggregates:
http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/.

Here are couple on domain events:
https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html 
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/13/a-better-domain-events-pattern/

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation. can I ask clarification - if there is only 1 repository for AR, how can repo handle save of child entities. There is a life cycle - sometimes AR will only have Customer populated, sometimes Both customer and Property will be populated and sometimes all 3 - Customer, Property and Decision will be available. How can one "Save" method of ARRepository handle save for all child entities? If AR already has Customer saved and Property object is being saved, by calling single "Save" on repository Customer will get saved again as part of saving Property.

Comment: Your welcome :) I will add the clarification as an update the my answer because comments have limited number of characters and I like to give detailed explanations